# rails 3: configuring devise emails to send extra mail to me

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to send an email (different from what is sent to the user) to me whenever a user account is confirmed, locked, etc. How can I configure devise to send these extra mails e.g. on confirm, send an email to me?

Comment: I have found the answer here: https://gist.github.com/982181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this gist does exactly what I was looking for: https://gist.github.com/982181 (couldn't answer it yesterday, sorry about that)

Answer (score 0):

You can override specific methods to achieve it.

Check 
[confirm!](http://send_unlock_instructionsrubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#confirm!-instance_method),
[send_unlock_instructions](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Lockable#send_unlock_instructions-instance_method) etc